# Unable to use Eager Load in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, relational-database, eloquent

I am trying to fetch "each user's avatar" from user table , using "relation" in laravel. Below are my Table and code. If i am doing any mistake, Kindly help.

I have Mention Model as below

```
<?php


class Mention extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'mention';

    protected $fillable = ['username', 'statusid', 'public'];

    public static $rules = [
        'username' => 'required|min:5',
        'statusid' => 'required|min:5',
        'public' => 'required'
    ];

    public function userget() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

User Model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password'];

    public static $rules = [
        'username' => 'required|min:5|alpha_num|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|min:5|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:5',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');


    public function mention() {
        return $this->hasMany('Mention', 'username');
    }


}
```

Below is my Mention table :-

```
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id         | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| username   | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| statusid   | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| created_at | timestamp           | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at | timestamp           | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Below is my User Table

```
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+
| id         | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI |
| username   | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |
| email      | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |
| password   | varchar(100)        | NO   |     |
| avatar     | varchar(100)        | NO   |     |
| created_at | timestamp           | NO   |     |
| updated_at | timestamp           | NO   |     |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+
```

I want to get each user's avatar from user table via mention table using "with" of laravel.

Below is my try :-

```
$next = Input::get('next') !== NULL ? Input::get('next') : 0;

$mention = Mention::with(array('userget' => function($query) {
    $query->where('username', '=', Auth::user()->username);
}))->skip($next)->take(5)->get()->toArray();
```

But this is giving "userget" always "null". Where I want.

It should return all row from "mention table" with "avatar" of their respective username.

Am i doing anything wrong in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to add the `wehere('username')` if you want all mentions with all users (regardless if it's the current auth user)

```
$mention = Mention::with('userget')->skip($next)->take(5)->get()->toArray();
```

### Update

To be able to use `username` as relation keys you need to specify them for the relation.

```
return $this->hasMany('Mention', 'username', 'username');
```

and

```
return $this->belongsTo('User', 'username', 'username');
```

**Note** I recommend again that you look into the whole foreign key thing. "I'm not really good with the foreign key stuff" is not an excuse. If you are serious about programming you should get good with it.

Comment: bro , `'userget' => null` is still "null"

Comment: Now I see the real problem, you don't have the standard foreign key `user_id` in your mention table. Are you sure you want to reference the user by username?

Comment: Yes, I want to reference user by `username` . I am not really good with "foreign key" stuff. So, i don't use them.

Comment: I still wouldn't recommend it. For example if you wanted to change the name you would need to update it everywhere. Also numbers are faster than strings

Comment: bro, I am not really good in foreign key, that is why, I am not able to use them.

Comment: w00t, that worked. Could you please explain me why there is 2 `username` in both `hasMany` and in `belongsTo`

Comment: Because both columns defining the relationship are named `username`. The one that identifies a user (User table) and the one that references a user (Mention table)